# Selenide and bonigarcia

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenide

I'm trying to use Selenide and bonigarcia together with using multiple web driver, such as Chrome, Mozilla, Edge and etc.
This is what I've done:

```
public static Selenide driver;

public static void runBrowser(String browserName, String url) throws Exception {
    if(browserName.equals("Chrome")) {
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().browserVersion(browserConfiguration.chromeVersion).setup();
        Configuration.startMaximized = true;
        driver.open(url);
    }
    else if(browserName.equals("Firefox")) {
        WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().browserVersion(browserConfiguration.firefoxVersion).setup();
        Selenide.open(url);
    }
    else if(browserName.equals("Edge")) {
        WebDriverManager.edgedriver().browserVersion(browserConfiguration.edgeVersion).setup();
        driver.open(url);
    } else {
        throw new Exception("Something went wrong opening browser");
    }
}
```

But, when I am trying to call that method with the parameter of "Firefox" or "Edge", it always runs on chrome. So, every time when I call that method, chromes web driver is running.

I've made it with Selenium, the difference between them is that instead of `Selenide.open(url)`, I use `WebDriver.get(url)` and it works fine when I call a method with "Firefox" or "Edge" parameter.

Any ideas?

**EDIT: **

I added `Configuration.browser = FirefoxDriverFactory.class.getName();` and now it looks like that: `WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().browserVersion(browserConfiguration.firefoxVersion).setup(); Configuration.browser = FirefoxDriverFactory.class.getName(); Selenide.open(url);`
It will open any browser which I want, Chrome, Mozilla, Edge, etc.
But, somehow, I don't think that this is a real solution. I don't even know what have I done with adding `FirefoxDriverFactory.class.getName()` and why it is working now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Selenide already includes WebDriverManager from bonigarcia.

You can just choose the browser either with

`Configuration.browser = "firefox";`

or setting SystemProperty selenide.browser, e.g. `-Dselenide.browser=firefox`

You don't need any Factories, WebDriverManager calls etc.

Comment: Thanks, I really did not knew that !

Comment: I think this is a feature introduced from Selenide 5 onwards. Really useful!